# Jquery Switching src of image on hover

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a long list of locations that is returned via an ajax call. When a user hovers over one of these locations a google static image is replaced with the location of the div they highlighted.

Each div is part of the locations class and has an attribute called location which is filled with by php. The div being updated is called #default. All this worked before I started doing it with an ajax call. Now it won't even recognize hovers (I made the source some random google image and it wouldn't change it).

How can I get this working and can someone explain why scripts don't work after putting them in ajax calls? I'm converting large parts of my site and this problem will continue to pop up if I don't figure out what is causing the problem.

Thanks!

```
<script>
$(".locations").hover(function(e) {

  var id = this.id; 
  var local= $(this).attr("location"); 
  $("#default").attr("src","http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+ local +"&zoom=16&size=235x144")


});
</script>
```

Comment: You need to look at adding events to elements using jQuery. Are you sure that you are assigning the hover function when the DOM is ready? Show us more code and we can try and help out.

Comment: Ajax returns locations in this form:
<div id='<? echo "post$id"; ?>' class="locations" location="<? echo "$latitude,$longitude"; ?>">
                      <p><? echo $text; ?>
                      <p class="smalllabel"><? echo "<a class='geosmall' href='profile.php?u=$add_short'>$add_first $add_last</a>"; ?> <? echo "$time $newdistance miles"; ?></div

Answer (score 0):

You are binding all elements that have a class "locations" to execute the method on hover BEFORE there are any elements with the "locations" class on the page (since the locations are loaded later asynchronously with ajax). There are a few ways to do this. 1) Perform the binding after the ajax call has come back successfully or 2) bind all future elements with the class "locations" with this event.

Apparently the hover event is not a real event it is just a shorthand for mouseenter and mouseleave added together. http://api.jquery.com/hover/  (You learn something new every day)

### Method 2

```
$(".locations").live("mouseenter",function(e) {
    var id = this.id; 
    var local= $(this).attr("location"); 
    $("#default").attr("src","http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/staticmap?center="+ local +"&zoom=16&size=235x144")
});
```